# Right click script alter table disabled in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, alter-table

I want to script a table as Alter to a New Query Editor Window. But this option is disabled. How can I do this?

Comment: Honestly NONE of these answers really reflect WHY is this disabled, it may as well not even be on right click the list given this answer set.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss honestly he is not asking WHY it is disabled but how to achieve what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: @VladL perhaps/agree in this context. This is IMHO a UI defect in SSMS with an "unfulfilled promise" by MS implied by the very existence of the disabled option in this context due the to inability to really do this because of its complexity of any `ALTER` which leads people to try to figure why it is disabled.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss is that the reason for the downvote? :)

Comment: I don't think the ALTER option was ever possible for a Table in SSMS.  You script an ALTER statement for a View this way.  But to an ALTER a table you need to follow the steps in the accepted answer.  Basically - the option is always disabled for a Table, but available for some other types of database objects

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use the "Design" function in SQL Server Management Studio to generate the ALTER script for you:

- Right-click on the table you want to alter and choose Design.
- Add new columns, change field types, set your fields to accept NULLS or not, etc.
- Once you are done, click the Generate Change Script toolbar button (or right-click on any column or in the white space).  This button looks like a floppy disk hovering over a piece of curled paper
- Save the result to a text file

Depending on how you have your SSMS options set, this may not be available initially if the changes require tables to be dropped and re-created.  To change this option, on the Tools menu, click Options, expand Designers, and then click Table and Database Designers. Select or clear the Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created check box.

Comment: This option "Generate Change Script" is permanently greyed out in SSMS! Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @MC9000 The "Generate Change Script" will not enable unless you actualy DO change something in the design.

Answer (score 29):

1) Right-click on the table you want to alter and choose Design

2) Add your new columns, change the field types, set your fields to accept NULLS or not, etc.

**Important:** Don't save your changes now

3) Do a right-click on any column or in the white space and you’ll see the option Generate Change Script is now available.

Comment: This option "Generate Change Script" is permanently greyed out in SSMS! Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @MC9000 it is enabled after you've done some changes, not before

Comment: no, it's something else - it's greyed out, regardless, unfortunately.  I solved it by using an alter table script which i do from here on out (the GUI is too flakey)

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server Management Studio 2016, toolbar button icon has changed. See the highlighted new icon.

[image: New Icon for Generate Change Script]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can access this dialog box after you have made unsaved changes to a table in Table Designer. On the Table Designer menu, click Generate Change Script.

2.Automatically generate change script on every save
If checked, the Save Change Script dialog box will appear any time you save changes to a table.

**Yes**
Bring up the Save dialog box where you can choose the location for the text file.

**No**
Cancel the creation of the change script.